# A regular expression (regex) for allowing numbers starts from 0 and after point two digit allow

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have regular expressions that allow numbers **from 0 to 999999999999999999.99**
which is allow

1. After a point it will only be two-digit (eg. 151531.99)
2. Allow Integer like 1, 2, 3565, 48784, 87848541, 151515

I have found one regex which is `[+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9])`
But it does not look above condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `|[0-9]` is an alternative that matches a single digit.

In this part `[0-9]*\.[0-9]+` the digits and to are optional so it can match a leading dot as well.

You can match 1-18 digits and optional dot and 2 digits. Using anchors to prevent a partial match.

```
^\+?\d{1,18}(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ihtFj8/1)

Comment: it's working in my condition, Thank you so much for your help.